# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt in c# (Access violation)

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, access-violation

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int DecompressMCX(object hComp,ref byte[] @in, uint @in_len, ref byte[] @out, ref uint out_len, bool eod);

public class XceedCompressor
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);       

    byte[] OutRec = new byte[1024 * 100];
    uint outlen;
    DecompressMCX DecompressDelegate;
    int b ;
    unsafe int l;

    public XceedCompressor()
    {
        IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary(@"xceedzip.dll");
        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = GetProcAddress(pDll, "XcUncompress");
        DecompressDelegate = (DecompressMCX)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(DecompressMCX));
    }

    public byte[] Decompress(byte[] InRecArr)
    {
        outlen = 0;
        l = DecompressDelegate(b, ref InRecArr, (uint)InRecArr.Length, ref OutRec, ref outlen, true);
        return OutRec;
    }
}
```

This is my class where I want to perform decompression.

```
XceedCompressor xcd = new XceedCompressor ();
xcd.Decompress(some data already compressed with the same library);
```

But its giving error as **"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."**

http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/Xceedzip/Uncompress_method.html

is the function which I want to pinvoke.
Hope for the best solution, as I always find here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm skeptical about these arrays declared `ref`.

Comment: Yes, the arrays are the problem. I can't make sense of the documentation of the native function mind you.

Comment: but then what is the solution, as I am supposed to achieve this any how ????

Comment: Far and away the easiest way to consume the Xceed ZIP library is to use their .net component. Trying to p/invoke a native version is just masochism. What's more, why would you use this library rather than a native .net library? For example, `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`.

Comment: because i am suppose to decompress live multicast data bytes of one of the stock exchange, whose API says that use xceedzip to decompress. And as a small project, buying such an expensive .net component is not possible for me.

Comment: @Nikki `xceedzip` is not free: €630/yr. And if you are going to use `xceedzip` you just use their .net version and have no problems. The fact that you are not doing that suggests that you are breaking their license agreement and trying to use their runtime DLL without purchasing a developer license. Don't do that. If you need to unzip and you have no money, use a free zip library. For example `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` which is part of .net!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you are not using Xceed's CSharp Lib or an alternative Zip library?
You should define your delegate as

> public delegate int DecompressMCX(int hComp,IntPtr in, uint in_len, IntPtr out, ref uint out_len, bool eod);

When generating the `in` IntPtr, it is important to fix it, so that the Garbage collector does not move the in data while the compression is running.

Comment: because i am suppose to decompress live multicast data bytes of one of the stock exchange, whose API says that use xceedzip to decompress. And as a small project, buying such an expensive .net component is not possible for me.

Comment: Thanks, your soln to change the delegate removed above error, but still decompression is not achieved.

Comment: I would expect that the xceedzip is basically zlib. you could alsi try to use the .NET framework classes for streams (IO.Streams). Which exchange is providing such an odd suggestion.

Comment: How would you fix the IntPtr?

Comment: @Meekohi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement